# how to inspect jquery code on chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use web developer tools to inspect html and subsequently see the css that is attached to the html element. This is proving to be a great process for learning from other websites (and the debugging my own)

Is there a way to inspect the javascript as well? So when I select the element, to be able to see the javascript related to the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [element panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) you can find all information related to an element including events attached to it.

You can use [console in the element panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to inspect an element using  `dir(elementId)`which dumps the object with the given id, as a JavaScript object with its properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can see javascript code that is attached as event to any element on the page. In Developer tools its in the Elements tab and each element has "Event Listeners" - there you see what events and what javascript will be catched and executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have been wandering a bit until I found how to do it on Chrome:

**1.** Open the Inspector <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

**2.** Select the element that you would like to inspect

**3.** Click on the `Event Listeners` tab

**4.** Click on the link next to the event listener you would like to check

**5.** Click on `Pretty Print` (Symbolized as {} at the bottom of the window)